# Factor group of direct product by restricted direct product

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $W:=\prod_{i\in \omega} F_i$ be the (external) unrestricted direct product and $U:=\prod_{i\in \omega}^w F_i$ be the (external) restricted direct product of finite groups $F_i$ such that $|F_{i}|<|F_{i+1}|$ for every $i\in\omega$. What can be said about $W/U$? Is $W/U$ residually finite (while $W$ is residually finite), for example?

Comment: Take $F_i=\mathbf{Z}/p_i\mathbf{Z}$, where $p_i$ is prime and $p_i\to\infty$. Then your quotient contains $\mathbf{Q}$ as subgroup, hence is not residually finite.

Comment: If the $F_i$ have unbounded exponent then the near product ($\prod F_i/\bigoplus F_i$) is also not residually finite. I even think it's not an iff condition: fix an odd prime $p$ and take the Heisenberg group of order $p^{2n+1}$ (central product of $n$ copies of the group of order $p^3$ of exponent $p$): the near product might fail to be residually finite.

Comment: The condition that $|F_{i}|<|F_{i+1}|$ is redundant. If $\prod_{i\in\omega}G_{i}$ is a product of finite groups and infinitely many of these groups are non-trivial, then there is an increasing sequence $(n_{k})_{k\in\omega}$ with $n_{0}=0$ such that if $F_{k}=G_{n_{k}}\times\dots\times G_{n_{k+1}-1}$, then $|F_{k}|<|F_{k+1}|$ for all $k$, and here $\prod_{k\in\omega}F_{k}/\text{Fin}\simeq\prod_{i\in\omega}G_{i}/\text{Fin}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $F_i$, $i\ge 1$, be a sequence of finite groups such that for every prime $p$ the orders of all but finitely many groups $F_i$ are not divisible by $p$. Then your group $W/U$ has no homomorphism onto a nontrivial finite group. Indeed if $G$ is a finite nontrival homomorphic image and $\phi: W/U\to G$ is a homomorphism,  $n=|G|$, $1\ne a\in G$, $b\in W/U, \phi(b)=a$ then $b=c^n$ for  some $c\in W/U$, therefore $a=\phi(c)^n=1$ in $G$, a contradiction. In particular $W/U$ is not residually finite. I used the fact that if a prime $p$ does not divide the order of a finite group $F$ then every element of $F$ has a root of degree $p$. Thus every element of $W$ has a root of degree $p$ modulo $U$.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment and the answer. So there seems to be some possibilities to be residually finite.

Comment: I did not add any comment.Of course, sometimes $W/U$ is residually finite. For example if all $F_i$ are Abelian of exponent  $2$ then $W/U$ is Abelian of exponent 2 and so is residually finite.

Comment: (You need to ask $|F_i|>1$ — actually it's enough to have just one prime divisor of the order tending to infinity). This answer actually follows from my comment, since this contains $Z/p_iZ$ for some primes $p_i\to\infty$, and hence the "near product" contains a copy of $Q$ (actually, of $R$).

Comment: One step further: $W/U$ may have a $p$-subgroup $T/U$ for some prime $p$. So $T/U \cap  Q/U=1$ where $Q/U$ is the isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $W/U$. Is $T/U$ residually finite in this case?

Comment: If $T/U$ is infinite, it may be isomorphic to the Prüfer group $C_{p^\infty}$ which is not residually finite.

Comment: Actually, the groups that I consider in $W/U$ are perfect reduced (so do not contain any $p^\infty$-type subgroups) non-(residually finite) $p$-groups with every proper subgroup residually finite. I am looking forward such groups in W/U.

Comment: Perfect  usually means it coincides with its derived subgroup. What is a "reduced" group? These are usually Abelian without divisible non-trivial subgroups, which contradicts "perfect". So what do you mean?

Comment: I use the term “reduced” in terms of semi-radicable (or quasi-radicable) groups on p.129 of Derek J. S. Robinson’s book [Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups, Part 2] or [D. McDougall, The subnormal strucure of some classes of soluble groups, {\it J. Austral. Math. Soc. 13(3), 365-377 (1972)].

Comment: A group $G$ is called {\it quasi-radicable} if $G=G^m=\langle g^m:g\in G\rangle$ for every positive integer $m$. A group is called {\it reduced} if if it has no non-trivial quasi-radicable subgroup.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with what you wanted to ask. You may want to ask another question or at least modify this one.